# How to add value to javascript array two time or more?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is my code, I have two array and want to put them in other array what named data:

```
data=[];
atIndex=0;
//userInfo is name and last name of user:
userInfo=['Mohammad','Kermani'];
//userKnow is stuff what a user know:
userKnow=['php','javascript'];

data[atIndex]=userInfo;

data[atIndex]=userInfo;
data[atIndex]=userKnow;

//I want to send data with json,and decode it with php:
console.log(data);
```

**But now just the last data is in data**

maybe it is nested array or two demential array

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R925B/)

Comment: why you are using only index `0` for adding your values. And Why this is used multiple times `data[atIndex]=userInfo;data[atIndex]=userInfo;`. Use `Array.push()` to add elements to array

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `data.push()`?

Comment: @Barmar I need something like this:    ({Mohammad,Kermani},{php,javascript})

Comment: Use 'data.push()' for pushing

Comment: @Mohammad, if you know `push`, what's the problem?

Comment: what does `({Mohammad,Kermani},{php,javascript})` mean? Is that an array with two objects or an array with two arrays. That isn't valid json?

Comment: @Liam How is the valid json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it an array of objects...

```
data[atIndex] = { userInfo: userInfo, userKnow, userKnow };
```

which would be accessible like so:

```
var userInfo = data[0].userInfo;
var userKnow = data[0].userKnow;
```

Your JSON would end up looking something like this (line breaks are for readability):

```
[ 
    { userInfo: ['Mohammad', 'Kermani'], userKnow: ['php', 'javascript'] }
]
```

---

Personally, if you are looking to send user information with an array of what they know then consider an object structure like this:

```
var userObject = {
    name1: 'Mohammad',
    name2: 'Kermani',
    userKnow: ['php', 'javascript']
};
```

You can user this like so:

```
userObject.name1 = 'my name';// set name1
var name2 = userObject.name2;// get name2
```

Comment: I cant have access to data with var userInfo = data[0].userInfo; For example I want to take name

Comment: In my first example, `data[0].userInfo` is an array so you would access a value like `data[0].userInfo[0];// 'Mohammad'`